# How to obtain Linux kernel parameters for currently booted system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot

I wonder if there is a command can show which value is selected by current kernel for each item in the [admin-guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt).

According to [this blog](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/display-view-linux-kernel-parameters-for-booted/), "sysctl -a" can be used to obtain the kernel parameters for currently booted system. However, the key of items in the output does not fully match with this admin-guide. And it does not contain "intel_idle.max_cstate" which is listed in the admin-guide and manually set in /proc/cmdline. So I think "sysclt -a" is not what I want.

Comment: The kernel parameters (accessible and modifiable by the `sysctl` command or by direct access to `/proc/sys/` files) and the kernel command line (provided during boot and processed during kernel initialization) are two different things although the initialization of some kernel parameters will be influenced by parameters on the kernel command line.

Comment: You can also see the `intel_idle.max_cstate` value in the sysfs filesystem at `/sys/module/intel_idle/parameters/max_cstate`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks, but how could I obtain the value of each item listed in the admin-guide? Is there a general way to construct the sysfs path from its name, like "/sys/module/intel_idle/parameters/max_cstate" from "intel_idle.max_cstate" as you have mentioned.

Comment: Not in general, but similar command line parameters containing a dot to separate a module name from a module parameter should work in a similar way.